# Use Jquery/Auto Complete in Javascript popup window

Tags: jquery

I have created a popup window for myself . In an input element inside of this form (in the popup window) I would like to use `Jquery` and its `plugin Auto Complete`. Does anyone a way to do this? I've used `Jquery` and the plugin in other forms, but those have been placed inside a "`normal`" page, not a popup window created with `Javascript`.

Is there like an easy way to call the function that starts the whole auto complete thing? Because I surely cannot link in the auto complete `javascript` files once again, from the popup window?

Comment: Use this plugin http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Why the down vote for this post..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always encounter this with generated HTML, as JS handlers are applied on page load, and obviously that HTML doesn't exist at that time.

What you can do is take advantage of the way JS "bubbles" down the HTML hierachy.
I'm guessing you're loading the popup into a html of some-kind that does exist on page load, maybe an empty `<div id="mypopup"></div>` If so, you can just apply the JS to this using [jQuery On Method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to that element, as it's there to begin with.

Comment: Wimore : yes i am loading the pop up from another page.Could you please elaborate on using jquery on method as i am not very much familiar with Jquey or some links might be helpful Thanks

Comment: but how could i call autocomplete method inside on metod

Comment: Are you loading the html popup through AJAX actually, if so you can just use the Success function of AJAX to apply the `.autocomplete()` function. Or, just however you're loading in your HTML popup, just put a function to call the autocomplete after it's finishing appending the new HTML.